# how to deploy a .war file in jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins

I have created a .war file in javascript using ANT.I deployed it in tomcat server. But I want to deploy it using jenkins.Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: You will have to write a manual shell script which does the running of the ANT build and copying the file to tomcat, restarting the server etc and upload the shell script  to Jenkins as a task.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Deploy plugin for Jenkins. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin

Out of curiosity, how (and perhaps more importantly why) does one "create a .war file in javascript using ANT"?

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a deploy target to the build file. Then call that target from the job.

**Further Reading (external article)**

- http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-deploy-to-tomcat-using-ant.html